# Rails: No route found when JWT token use in URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a route with my JWT token as a path variable but it doesn't work with the JWT token `eyJhbGciOiJub25lIn0.eyJjb25maXJtYXRpb25fc2VudF9hdCI6IjIwMTgtMDEtMjQgMDY6MDQ6MzEgKzEzMDAiLCJleHBpcmVzX2F0IjoiMjAxOC0wMS0yNyAwNjowNDozMSArMTMwMCIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjM5fQ.`

When I switch the JWT token to something less complicated e.g. `5` then the route works. I'm guessing that the format of the JWT need some special treatment in the rails router?

```
get '/verify/:jwt', to: 'users#verify_email'

No route matches [GET] "/verify/eyJhbGciOiJub25lIn0.eyJjb25maXJtYXRpb25fc2VudF9hdCI6IjIwMTgtMDEtMjQgMDY6MDQ6MzEgKzEzMDAiLCJleHBpcmVzX2F0IjoiMjAxOC0wMS0yNyAwNjowNDozMSArMTMwMCIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjM5fQ
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  extend DeviseRoutes
  extend PageRoutes

  # Root route
  root to: "pages#home"
end
```

**devise_routes.rb**

```
module DeviseRoutes
  def self.extended(router)
    router.instance_exec do
      devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: {
      sign_in: 'login',
      sign_out: 'logout',
      sign_up: 'register',
      edit: '/user/edit'
      }, controllers: { registrations: 'users' }

      # User profile management
      devise_scope :user do
        get '/profile/:id', to: 'users#profile_home', as: 'profile'
        # Verify email
        get '/verify', to: 'users#verify_email'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**users_controller**

```
class UsersController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  include AuthenticationConcern

  require 'utilities/custom_mailer'
  require 'jwt'

  def profile_home
    @user_id = params[:id]
    check_user_route_access current_user, @user_id

    @user = User.includes(:skills).find_by(id: @user_id)
    @skills = @user.skills.eager_load(:profession)
  end

  def create
    super
    if current_user
      CustomMailer.send_initial_user_signup(user_id: current_user.id,
                                                            to_email: current_user.email,
                                                            user_full_name: current_user.full_name)
    end
  end

  def verify_email
    jwt_token = params[:token]
    @jwt_token_decoded = true

    # make sure the jwt_token can be decoded, if not crash softly via
    # error on the page rather than hard crash
    begin
      decoded = (JWT.decode jwt_token, nil, false)[0]
    rescue
      @jwt_token_decoded = false
    end

    if @jwt_token_decoded
      decoded_expires_at = decoded["expired_at"]
      user_id = decoded["user_id"]

      @user = User.find_by(id: user_id)

      # 1. if user is verified, redirect to login page
      if @user != nil and @user.confirmed_at != nil
        # flash[:success] = t('successfully_created')
        redirect_to new_user_session_path
      end

      # 2. once verified, provide option in view to go to login page
    end
    # render verification page
  end
end
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: There is no error in JWT token. Make sure you have correct code in `verify_email` method

Comment: Yeah I verified everything else. I ended up just using ‘?token=‘ in the URL for ‘params’ to work.

Comment: Yeah you can do this. But I don't find any issue in above route as well.

Comment: Can you post your entire `routes.rb` file?

Comment: This is likely caused by the dots in the token. Try adding , `jwt: /[\w.]+/ ` to your route declaration.

Comment: can u share `verify_email` method, also what params passing to generate JWT ?

Comment: shared the controller and routes :)

Answer (score 2):

In your route the JWT consists of various special characters like '.' because of which the rails router is unable to route it properly.

Solution :-

1:- Use route globbing using wildcard segments

Example :-

Change you route to this

```
get '/verify/*jwt', to: 'users#verify_email', constraints: { jwt: /.*/ }
```

This will give params[:jwt] = "passed jwt in url"

You can customize the regex used here to make it more meaningful for jwt token which consists of two '.' and other special characters.

Read this for more information :- [Rails route globbing and wildcard segments](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments)

Answer (score -1):

The most probable cause of this issue is that you have another route *before* than `get '/verify/:jwt', to: 'users#verify_email'`. Rails Router gives priority to the first instance it finds.

So if for example, your `routes.rb` looks like this:

```
resources :verify # this may not be your case, just an example
get '/verify/:jwt', to: 'users#verify_email'
```

In this case, rails will ignore `get` line, and whenever you `GET /verify/<anything>` will be routed to `verify#show`

On the other hand, if you swap those lines like this,

```
get '/verify/:jwt', to: 'users#verify_email'
resources :verify # this may not be your case, just an example
```

Then every `GET /verify/<anything>` will be routed to `verify_email`.